# Perform two sums with different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I need to perform two Sums with different conditions:

- First Sum: Must return the sum of values for each date1 and id (Group by date1 and id).
- Second Sum: Must return the sum of values for each date1 and id (Group by date1 and id), without the value corresponding to the smallest date2 .

| ID | Value | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 |
| 01 | 01 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 |
| 01 | 03 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-17 |
| 01 | 02 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-20 |
| 01 | 01 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-22 |
| 01 | 04 | 2022-02-16 | 2022-02-28 |

Expected outcome:

| ID | Date1 | SUM1 | SUM2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-02-15 | 05 | 04 |
| 01 | 2022-02-16 | 07 | 05 |

- In sum2, for data1=2022-02-15, the value corresponding to data2=2022-02-15 was removed, as it is the smallest value of data2 in the grouping.
- In sum2 , for data1 = 2022-02-16, the value corresponding to data2=2022-02-20 was removed, as it is the smallest value of data2 in the grouping.

Any suggestions on how to get this result?

Comment: did you try anything? can you create a db fiddle?

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a1d2bd5a028d4237103491ea02e86d42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `partition by` does not always play well with `group by`, you can use CTE to achieve the result:

```
with tmp as (
    select tv.*, first_value(value) over (partition by id, date1 order by date2) date2_value
    from table_views tv
)
select id, date1, sum(value) 
from tmp
group by id, date1
union all
select id, date1, sum(value) - min(date2_value)
from tmp
group by id, date1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=76013805220140c810d3fae39f6010be) is the db_fiddle.

I've used `min` here, but that is arbitraty and any other would work: `max`, `avg` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function in subquery which will get the next value per `Date1` (that will ignore the smallest per `Date1`).

Then do `sum` on `value` column & `LEAD` window function column.

```
SELECT ID,
       Date1,
       SUM(Value) SUM1,
       SUM(n_val) SUM2
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           LEAD(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Date1 ORDER BY Date2) n_val
    FROM table_views 
) t1
GROUP BY ID,Date1;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2a268b49929a034330b3c663d66c351a)